# Root partition available size decreasing after running several command in terminal

Tags: linux, partition, kali-linux, storage, parrotsec

I have a problem with my root partition. I use Ubuntu distribution with Parrot Distro. I dual boot Kali on top of Windows 10. My storage is 250gb. I manually partitioned at first installing the OS. 240gb for is `ext4` mounted on root, and 10gb left is for `swap area`.

And now is the real problem. I didn't install any software. But after running several command, my root partition available size is decreasing. It happens every time. I have tried many ways but it can't solve my problem.

Please I need help. And thank you before.

[image: First photo captured]

[image: running sudo du -h --max-depth=1]

[image: After running sudo du -h --max-depth=1]

[image: After running sudo apt autoremove]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Care to indicate what those commands that you didn't mention were? Edit your original question with this info. Also how big is your `/home` directory (all contents) - I think its probably quite big.

Comment: Update the question including (text) outputs of `swapon -s` and `du -shx --exclude=/{proc,sys,dev} /*`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for posting images of text. I rarely ask on stackexchange

Comment: This applies not only to stackexchange, but to *any* place. If it's text, copy-paste it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this been a while. So the problem is in my Wireless Wi-Fi adapter using TP-Link TL-WN881ND that isn't compatible. So the kernel keeps printing a log message. So that's the cause of root partition is full.